# How can I change to a Google account without losing my Trainer Club account progress in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I am level 15 and have a Pokemon Trainer Club account but I am sick of the disconnects. I would like to change to a Google account.

Can I link these accounts or transfer data between the two?

Comment: Are you asking about the differences between a Google account and a Pokemon Trainer club account for Pokemon Go?

Comment: @twobugs He wants to transfer from PTC to Google

Answer (score 3):

You can not switch to another account and keep you data and you can not transfer your data from one account to another. If you started with a trainer account you will have to keep it or start a new character from level 1.

This might be subject to change, if Niantic feels like it, but for now you have no choice.